# set style to checked + child of element in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

i have some checkbox and some span tag inside them. how can i set style to span when input checked?
the html code :

```
<div className="m-4">
                    <p id="id_work_days">
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700 ' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="1"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>sun</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="2"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>Mon</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="3"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>Tue</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="4"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>wen</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="5"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>Fri</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="6"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>Thu</span></label>
                        <label><input className='hidden checked:child:bg-gray-700' type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="7"/><span className='inline-block p-3 mx-4 bg-gray-200 text-slate-700 rounded-2xl shadow-xl '>Fri</span></label>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

the css code that i want to do :

```
#id_work_days input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`peer`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) on `input` and `peer-checked:bg-gray-700` on `span`

*Note that I'm using `className` as yours but in [this sandbox](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WxQh57xP0P), I'm using `class` for usual style usage*

```
<div className="m-4">
  <p id="id_work_days">
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="1" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">sun</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="2" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">Mon</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="3" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">Tue</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="4" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">wen</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="5" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">Fri</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="6" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">Thu</span></label>
    <label><input className="peer hidden" type="checkbox" name="work_days" value="7" /><span className="mx-4 inline-block rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-3 text-slate-700 shadow-xl peer-checked:bg-gray-700">Fri</span></label>
  </p>
</div>
```